# Android Cordova app Builds but when clicked on run gives issue

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, hybrid

When i clean built my Cordova apps it builds properly but when i click on run it gives following issue:

E:\trash\morning\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\camera\CordovaUri.java

Error:(6, 34) error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
E:\trash\morning\platforms\android\src\com\adobe\phonegap\push\GCMIntentService.java

Error:(18, 30) error: package android.support.v4.app does not exist

Error:(19, 30) error: package android.support.v4.app does not exist

Error:(20, 49) error: package android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat does not exist

Error:(332, 65) error: package NotificationCompat does not exist

Error:(379, 72) error: package NotificationCompat does not exist

Error:(389, 99) error: package NotificationCompat does not exist

Error:(407, 85) error: package NotificationCompat does not exist

Error:(480, 89) error: package NotificationCompat does not exist

Error:(497, 75) error: package NotificationCompat does not exist

Error:(516, 75) error: package NotificationCompat does not exist

Error:(532, 117) error: package NotificationCompat does not exist

Error:(561, 134) error: package NotificationCompat does not exist

Error:(579, 75) error: package NotificationCompat does not exist

Error:(236, 27) error: package NotificationCompat does not exist
Error:(237, 39) error: package NotificationCompat does not exist

Error:(338, 45) error: package NotificationCompat does not exist
Error:(338, 97) error: package NotificationCompat does not exist
Error:(361, 39) error: package NotificationCompat does not exist

Error:(362, 50) error: package NotificationCompat.Action does not exist

Error:(371, 37) error: cannot find symbol class WearableExtender

Error:(425, 35) error: package NotificationCompat does not exist
Error:(425, 89) error: package NotificationCompat does not exist
Error:(435, 35) error: package NotificationCompat does not exist
Error:(435, 81) error: package NotificationCompat does not exist
Error:(445, 31) error: package NotificationCompat does not exist
Error:(445, 83) error: package NotificationCompat does not exist
Error:(457, 31) error: package NotificationCompat does not exist
Error:(457, 77) error: package NotificationCompat does not exist

Error:(521, 33) error: cannot find symbol variable NotificationCompat

Error:(521, 80) error: cannot find symbol variable NotificationCompat

E:\trash\morning\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\camera\CameraLauncher.java

Error:(64, 34) error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist

Error:(295, 40) error: cannot find symbol variable FileProvider

Error:(797, 39) error: cannot find symbol variable FileProvider

Error:Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>   Information:BUILD FAILED

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the camera plugin in your cordova application...

Comment: Yes, added the camera plugin in cordova application... Having this issue when now i added "cordova-plugin-googleplus " plugin..

Comment: Did you get the solution @Abhijit